# Add data to http response using rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a trip entity which contains driver id.
I can get fetch trip using RESTFull endpoint, e.g. `/trips/2/`.

```
//example response
{
  id: "2",
  driver_id: "123"
}
```

I can fetch driver details using the endpoint. e.g. `/drivers/123/`,
My final respected response is

```
//expected response from observable
{
  id: "2",
  driver_id: "123",
  detailed_driver: {
    name: "abc",
    id: "123"
  }
}
```

Currently I do it as follows

```
this.http("/trips/2/").map(data => data.json()).subscribe(trip => {
   this.http("/drivers/" + trip.driver_id + "/").map(data => data.json()).subscribe(driver => {
      trip.detailed_driver = driver;
      this.trip = trip 
   }
}
```

How can I use Rxjs to use these two endpoints to get final expected response from a single observable?

Comment: can you add your current fetch code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `flatMap` operator and `Observable.forkJoin` as described below:

```
this.http.get('/trips/someid')
   .map(res => res.json())
   .flatMap(res => {
     return Observable.forkJoin([
       Observable.of(res),
       this.http.get('/drivers/'+res['driver_id']).map(res => res.json())
     ]);
   })
   .map(res => {
     res[0]['detailed_driver'] = res[1];
     return res[0]
   })
 .subscribe(
   (data) => {
   }
 );
```

The `flatMap` allows to execute another request when the first one is received. `Observable.forkJoin` allows to receive both the response of the first response and the result of the second one at the end.

This way you will be able to update the first result with the second one...

Comment: what's wrong in here http://plnkr.co/edit/opyzLR4ejKdLPGfWM7EN?p=preview click on `friend tab` and look at `frineds.ts`. I tried to implement your suggested code but not working with no error.

Comment: In fact, there is a typo in my code :-( The `}` at the end of the `forkJoin`... I updated my answer and fixed your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/BthgxpehFcR6fg9hBRMj?p=preview. Thanks for pointing this out @micronyks!

Comment: But I can't find required data in object `console.log(data)` . Could you please help me?

Comment: its worked! thanks... I needed to make few changes, like addedin `.map()res => res.json()` in the second `this.http.get()` and `return res[0]` in the final map function.